# Applying a single patch to files in multiple directories

Tags: diff, patch

Directory structures looks like this:

`orig/l1/l2/file2patch`

`orig/l1-2/file2patch`

Diff'd with

`new/l1/l2/file2patch`

`new/l1-2/file2patch`

I get the correct diff between these files and save it in a file but applying it has proved to be non-trivial.

I've tried `patch -d orig/ < patch.diff` but the `-d` expects the files that are to be patched should live immediately in `orig`

Is there some way I can have patch recur on a directory and apply the patch to the specified files that exist in the patch?

Comment: Look into the -p flag to tell patch your directory structure is different

Comment: @JeffSchaller I have two different directories that have two different levels.

Comment: @cbrad You misunderstand what the `-p` flag does. Read `man patch`, specifically the `-p` option.

Answer (score 1):

While the given pathnames do not look quite right (especially the `new` tree, which someone else has changed), you can keep in mind that the `patch` program can be told to ignore a given number of levels of directory from the output of `diff` using the `-p` option.

When applying a patch to files in a different directory than the patch-file shows, you would `cd` into the directory (to cancel one part of the mismatch) and use the `-p` option to adjust for the `cd`.

Here is a short script illustrating how I would solve this (using the dry-run option of GNU patch for a simple listing):

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /tmp/foo
OUT=/tmp/patch.diff
rm -f $OUT
diff -u orig/l1/l2/file2patch new/l1/l2/file2patch >>$OUT
diff -u orig/l1-2/file2patch new/l1-2/file2patch >>$OUT

diffstat -p1 $OUT
cd orig
patch -p1 --dry-run <$OUT
```

Inputs:

```
$ find . -type f
./new/l1/l2/file2patch
./new/l1-2/file2patch
./orig/l1/l2/file2patch
./orig/l1-2/file2patch
```

Output:

```
$ /tmp/xx
 l1-2/file2patch  |   19 +++++++++++++------
 l1/l2/file2patch |    5 ++---
 2 files changed, 15 insertions(+), 9 deletions(-)
/tmp/foo/orig
patching file l1/l2/file2patch
patching file l1-2/file2patch
```

Further reading:

- [**`diff`** - *compare two files*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/diff.html) (POSIX)
- [**`patch`** - *apply changes to files*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/patch.html) (POSIX)
- [**`diffstat`** - *make histogram from diff-output*](http://invisible-island.net/diffstat/diffstat.html)